# How can I install VLC on RHEL 6.3?

Tags: redhat, yum, 32bit-64bit, video

I'm having a problem installing VLC on Red hat 6.3

When I try to use

```
yum install vlc
```

all goes well until it shows me this in the end:

> Error: Package: vlc-2.0.3-6.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
>              Requires: libminizip.so.1()(64bit)
>
> Error: Package: liblrdf-0.5.0-2.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
>              Requires: ladspa
>
> Error: Package: libffado-2.1.0-0.8.20120325.svn2088.el6.x86_64 (linuxtech-release)
>              Requires: libconfig++.so.8()(64bit)

also I can't use

```
yum update
```

I'm running on a 32-bit processor and I don't know what's wrong.

ok I'v installed live555 and tried again nothing really happened here is my

`yum whatprovides *BasicUsageEnviroment`

> `live555-devel-0-0.34.2012.01.25.el6.x86_64 : Development files for live555.com streaming
>                                              : libraries
>   Repo        : linuxtech-release
>   Matched from:
>   Filename    : /usr/include/BasicUsageEnvironment
>
> live555-devel-0-0.34.2012.01.25.el6.i686 : Development files for live555.com streaming
>                                            : libraries
>   Repo        : linuxtech-release
>   Matched from:
>   Filename    : /usr/include/BasicUsageEnvironment
>
> live555-devel-0-0.27.2010.04.09.el6.rf.x86_64 : Development files for live555.com streaming
>                                                 : libraries
>   Repo        : rpmforge
>   Matched from:
>   Filename    : /usr/include/BasicUsageEnvironment
>
> live555-devel-0-0.27.2012.02.04.el6.rf.x86_64 : Development files for live555.com streaming
>                                                 : libraries
>   Repo        : rpmforge
>   Matched from:
>   Filename    : /usr/include/BasicUsageEnvironment

@quanta it's still persists `with yum install vlc`  , sorry man but I can't run any of my videos it requires updated codec and I can't get any

@quanta here is my yum repolist

> > repo id                                                                   repo name                                                                                                       status
> >     elrepo                                                                    ELRepo.org Community Enterprise Linux Repository - el6                                                            219
> >     epel                                                                      Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                                                  7,774
> >     linuxtech-release                                                         LinuxTECH.NET el6 production repo                                                                                 934
> >     rpmforge                                                                  RHEL 6Server - RPMforge.net - dag                                                                               4,434
> >     repolist: 13,361

the output is

Setting up Install Process
No package vlc.i686 available.
Error: Nothing to do

When I tried to use `yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=rpmforge install vlc`

it showed me this at the end

> Error: Package: libcaca-0.99-0.1.beta17.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
>              Requires: libglut.so.3()(64bit)
>   Error: Package: dirac-1.0.2-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
>              Requires: libcppunit-1.12.so.1()(64bit)

**Note**: `yum install vlc.i686` doesn't work either and it shows me more Error: Package

Comment: `arch`? `yum repolist`? `yum install vlc.i686`?

Comment: Append the output of `yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=rpmforge install vlc` to your question?

Comment: `yum --disablerepo=epel install vlc`?

Comment: the same original flaw

Comment: `yum --disablerepo=epel install freeglut`?

Comment: Setting up Install Process
No package freeglut available.
Error: Nothing to do
same with 
'yum install freeglut'

Comment: http://tharindu.info/2011/05/06/adding-dvd-as-base-repository-in-rhel-6/

Comment: but I'm subscribed to Red hat without support

Comment: Feel free to add DVD as base repo and install required packages from this.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you with this but the instructions in the link doesn't work for me either :( when I use mkdir /mnt/cd it keeps showing me that mkdir: cannot create directory `/mnt/cd': File exists
I really regret installing Lunix and thanks for your effort anyway

Comment: Do the next step `mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cd`.

Comment: mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only

Comment: `yum --disablerepo=epel install freeglut`?

Comment: Setting up Install Process
No package freeglut available.
Error: Nothing to do
I'v been able to install wine and deluge without having any problems

Comment: `yum repolist`?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/822/repoy.jpg/

Comment: No base repo from DVD?

Comment: I'v installed base repos

Comment: what to do now ?

Comment: Examine with `yum repolist`, then re-install `vlc`.

Comment: still not good ... same error

Comment: Please show us again?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/f/818/snapshot2w.jpg/
http://imageshack.us/f/818/snapshot2w.jpg/

Comment: I don't see the base repo in list. You forgot to disable epel repo (x86_64).

Comment: so how to disable it ?

Comment: Guys! Take it to chat or I'm locking this Q. Thank you!

Comment: @ChrisS: holddame cannot chat with 1 rep.

Answer (score 4):

You are installing 64-bit package on 32-bit OS. Try this:

`rpm -ivh http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/vlc-1.1.13-1.el6.rf.i686.rpm`

---

On my CentOS:

```
# yum whatprovides *BasicUsageEnvironment
...
live555-devel-0-0.27.2010.04.09.el5.rf.x86_64 : Development files for live555.com streaming libraries
Repo        : rpmforge
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/include/BasicUsageEnvironment

live555-devel-0-0.27.2012.02.04.el5.rf.x86_64 : Development files for live555.com streaming libraries
Repo        : rpmforge
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/include/BasicUsageEnvironment
```

So, install `live555` and try again:

`# rpm -ivh http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/live555-0-0.27.2012.02.04.el6.rf.i686.rpm http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/i386/rpmforge/RPMS/live555-devel-0-0.27.2012.02.04.el6.rf.i686.rpm`

Comment: so what can i do to install 32-bit packages ?

Comment: I'm appreciating your effort but I used the code and it shows me this 

error: Failed dependencies:                                                                
        libBasicUsageEnvironment.so.0 is needed by vlc-1.1.13-1.el6.rf.i686                
 and I'v tried to install it form http and the result was this 
The name org.freedesktop.PackageKit was not provided by any .service files

Comment: @holddame: `BasicUsageEnvironment` is included in `live555` package. updated my answer.

Comment: If you're going to use a bunch of rpmforge RPMs, why not just install the repo?

Comment: I'm kinda beginner in Lunix thing :) 
so how would i install the repo ?

Comment: `rpm -ivh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.i686.rpm`.

Comment: done .. it's installed .. tried again nothing happened though

Comment: `yum install vlc`?